# AVKit not found in cocoa using xcode 5

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm have developing one video play application in cocoa. I got one sample code then tried to run. but got exception is "AVKIt is not found".

below link i got source 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVKitPlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html

I'm using Xcode 5.0 or later, OS X v10.9.1

after i found and copy AVKIT.Framework in the following location "/System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework" and added my project after then also im getting same exception.

Ref ; https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVKit/Reference/AVKitFramework/_index.html

[image]

Any once please help me how i can run this code and add AVKit.framework in application

Answer (score 0):

if the value of Base SDK in build setting is Latest OS X(10.8), you must be using XCode 5.0, the OS X 10.9 Base SDK is shipped only after XCode 5.0.1.

So just update your XCode to 5.0.1 or above, AVKit is there.